# Como limpar o campo no Angular?

Tags: angular

Observem a imagem gif;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou trabalhando em um projeto Angular, o que preciso é ao usuário trocar de CPF para CNPJ além de realizar a troca dos campos ele possa também limpar o campo quando for trocado, não é o que acontece de acordo com a imagem.

Como faço para limpar o campo CPF e CNPJ quando eu troca o tipo de pessoa?

Eu gostaria de realizar a mudança no HTML invés de ser no componente da pagina Angular, observem o código correspondente;

```
<div class="form-group col-3 marginTop">
  <label>Tipo de Pessoa</label>
  <select name="tipoPessoa" [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.tipoPessoa" class="form-control">
    <option value="F">CPF</option>
    <option value="J">CNPJ</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-3 inputAjuste">
  <div *ngIf="filtroDevedor.tipoPessoa == 'F'">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">CPF</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" maxlength="14" mask="000.000.000-00" class="form-control" name="cpfCnpj"
        [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="filtroDevedor.tipoPessoa == 'J'">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">CNPJ</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" maxlength="18" mask="00.000.000/0000-00" class="form-control" name="cpfCnpj"
        [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando o mesmo **model -> [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj"** para os dois `input`, logo, quando digita-se algo no **CPF** isso fica armazenado no model e quando muda no select para **CNPJ** o input já vem com o valor do model, ou seja, o valor do CPF.

> Eu gostaria de realizar a mudança no HTML invés de ser no componente da pagina Angular

Creio não haver como fazer isso só no Html, mas, com poucas mudanças você consegue chegar no resultado que deseja:

**HTML:** Insira uma função do evento **onchange** no select:

```
<div class="form-group col-3 marginTop">
  <label>Tipo de Pessoa</label>
  <select name="tipoPessoa" [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.tipoPessoa" class="form-control" (change)="valor()">
    <option value="F">CPF</option>
    <option value="J">CNPJ</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-3 inputAjuste">
  <div *ngIf="filtroDevedor.tipoPessoa == 'F'">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">CPF</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" maxlength="14" mask="000.000.000-00" class="form-control" name="cpfCnpj" [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="filtroDevedor.tipoPessoa == 'J'">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">CNPJ</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" maxlength="18" mask="00.000.000/0000-00" class="form-control" name="cpfCnpj" [(ngModel)]="filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS:** Na função **`valor()`** toda as vezes que o select mudar, a variável **filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj** será limpa:

```
valor() {
  this.filtroDevedor.cpfCnpj = '';
}
```